# Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView on Android 5.1.1

Tags: java, android

I have a search view in XML defined like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/sugSearchView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                    android:textDirection="firstStrongRtl"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:defaultQueryHint="Search for videos"
                    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:queryHint="Search for videos">

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>
```

I have a crash on Android 5.1.1 devices, i get:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #150: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView

"Caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=6; index=7"
```

I've googled it and found nothing. How can I solve this one? Does version 5.1.1 support `androidx.searchview`?

Comment: there are six items in whatever array that is.. you are trying to get the 7th element

Comment: Its an inflation exception only happens on android 5,1,1...

Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #150: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView

Comment: post your code where you are using ArrayList.

Comment: Im not using array list. the IndexOutOfBounds is because of the Android system inflater

Answer (score 0):

in your question error is

```
 "Caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=6; index=7"
```

means you have one list of 6 elements and you are trying to access 7th element

Put the limit of array size or manage it as per your requirement

Comment: I've edited my question. It's an InflateException
Binary XML file line #150: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView

Only happens on 5.1.1 devices.. all other OS versions (above 5.1.1) is good

Comment: can you post a complete xml file?

Answer (score 0):

its because of this line  android:textDirection="firstStrongRtl"
I too had the same crash and when I changed to ltr.it stopped crashing in 5.1